# PHP file_get_contents of HTML file requests old resources

Tags: javascript, php, file-get-contents

I have a certain webpage. This is the file structure:

```
index.php
script.js
style.css
edit
 |
 |--- index.php
 |
 |--- script.js
```

`edit/index.php` is echoing the contents of `index.php` using `file_get_contents('../index.php')` which contains `<script src='script.js'></script>`. `edit/script.js` contains `alert()`. When I open `https://www.example.com/edit`, it displays the contents of `index.php`, but it doesn't execute the code inside `edit/script.js`. Why is this happening and how can I fix this? (Although `index.php` has the extension `.php` it doesn't contain any PHP, just HTML)

Comment: What MIME type are you sending this back as? if it's just `text/plain` then the browser *will not* interpret any HTML. If it is set as HTML then a reference to `script.js` will use the one in the `edit/` path since that's a relative path.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I'm just using `echo file_get_contents('../index.php')`

Comment: Again, what MIME type is being set? Check in your browser's Network inspector. The MIME type determines **how the browser handles the content**, or if it handles it at all.

Comment: It's being sent as `text/html`. And as I mentioned in the question, I see exactly what I see in `index.php`. And in Chrome, when I view the source and go to `<script src='script.js'></script>` and click `script.js`, it takes me to `https://www.example.com/script.js` instead of `https://www.example.com/edit/script.js`

Comment: Have you checked in your browser’s network console if edit/script.js is loaded?

Comment: I just did, and it's requesting `script.js` instead of `edit/script.js`.

Comment: It seems you are using file_get_contents of the root index.php file to display something in your page. Use `include` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Relative URLs are parsed by the browser, not the server. It parses them relative to the URL that the browser loaded. The browser doesn't know that you got the file from a different directory, so it can't adjust how it processes the relative path.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. So you're suggesting that while I'm reading the contents of the file, I should change `<script src='script.js'></script>` to `<script src='edit/script.js'></script>`?

Comment: Another issue: why are you reading a PHP script with `file_get_contents()`? It won't execute any of the code, it will return it to the client verbatim.

Comment: That's a possibility, but it means you have to use an HTML parser to find the attributes you want to change. A better solution might be to use absolute URLs.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your help. Could you post these comments as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the browser doesn't know that `edit` is actually `edit/index.php`. It thinks that this is a file in the root directory, so when parses `script.js` it looks for that in the root directory as well.

You should configure the webserver so that it performs a redirect from `edit` to `edit/index.php`, rather than just returning the contents of `edit/index.php`. This way, all relative URLs will be processed correctly. If you don't want to show the script name, you could just redirect to `edit/` -- that's enough for it to know that this is a directory rather than a file.

Comment: Thank you for your help!